# Grouping by DateTime using LINQ properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime, group-by

I'm trying to group by sales by their sale date (order date in this case) and then sum all of the sales amounts made on that day. In the end, ordering the list by oldest date to newest like following:

```
 ViewBag.result = GraphList
                         .GroupBy(l => l.OrderDate.Date)
                         .Select(cl => new StoreAnalyticOrders
                         {
                             OrderDate = cl.Key.Date,
                             AmountPaid = cl.Sum(c => c.AmountPaid)
                         })
                         .OrderBy(x => x.OrderDate.Date)
                         .ToList();
```

I have checked and compared the results that I get with the actual data on eBay and the results are just not right... I get higher amounts for some date, while for some dates I get lower AmountPaid values...

Note: I cannot use Dbfunctions.TruncateTime since the data doesn't comes out of DB, but rather from API;

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: The datetime objects are in this format:

```
11/5/2016 5:12:51 PM
```

If this can help ?

Comment: The datetime format, is that Nov 5 or May 11? I would figure that out first. Then create a new datetime object from it using parse and ensure it returns the correct date. Otherwise you have to parse it into the expected value

Comment: this is Nov 5 2016 date... It actually groups some values just okay.. while some are showing wrong values, not really sure where the problem occurs..

Comment: That is not what I meant. If it's November 5 then does your application treat it as Nov 5? Depending on the setting of date format on the OS, it could be interpreted  differently by the application.

Comment: Well if you're asking the format of the date and time on my computer (OS) then it goes like this: 11/27/2016  <=== (27 Nov. 2016)

Comment: Then it's possible they are filtering certain records for reasons I am unaware of.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yeah that's what I've figured out as well... The dates on my eBay graph  are not matched by what their API returns... It's really odd...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129153/discussion-between-user987-and-codingyoshi).

Comment: Sorry i cant right now. On the subway going somewhere. Will try connecting with you later if you still have the issue.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Okay pm me when you have time :)

Comment: Do you have some of the raw data, say for one day?

Comment: @Johnatan yes, I have it stored in a XML file...

Comment: @Jonathan actually I have the data for the past 30 days...

Comment: Probably a UTC issue.

Comment: @GertArnold How would I fix this so that wherever I host the application it shows the right results?